# What causes sonatype nexus 3 to go into read only mode?

Tags: jenkins, nexus, sonatype, nexus3

Once in a while we get this error in our jenkins jobs:

```
Failed to transfer file: creativeFileName
Return code is: 503, ReasonPhrase: Nexus Repository Manager is in read-only mode.
```

We got jobs sceduled at night when other nexus tasks as f.e. compact blobstore, backup... are running. In order to scedule these jobs and tasks better i need to know which nexus tasks will cause a read-only mode?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The task to backup metadata that is most probably part of your backup scenario is setting nexus in readonly mode so that the backup is consistent.

https://help.sonatype.com/repomanager3/backup-and-restore/prepare-a-backup

From what I can recall it's the only "out-of-the-box" task type that will put nexus readonly.